# How can I get array value from Map<String, List<String>> and put into setOnMarkerClickListener?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get array value from Map<String, List> and put into setOnMarkerClickListener?

I can get the LatLng values and put into Google Map marker, then user click the marker can show title. But I want to replace marker to custom image. How can get values from image array? Because the image is must be upload, so I just want to get value [0].

When user click the marker I want to get PostID how do I send PostID into onMarkerClick?

this is firebase data

```
"Campsite" : {
    "-MfS3VgBGROs_afkVrjl" : {
      "CamperSiteAddress" : "Charles St & Esplanade W, Triabunna TAS 7190, Australia",
      "CamperSiteID" : "-MfS3VgBGROs_afkVrjl",
      "Counrty" : "Australia",
      "CamperSiteImages" : [
 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206575487.null?alt=media&token=bff07bd4-fd17-4099-a0d7-db0418311425", 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206580478.null?alt=media&token=995bf983-0ee8-4f25-af3f-921aa5b0077c", 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206584072.null?alt=media&token=137b87a9-f6fb-4f75-9d53-7c3efda8cda4" 
],
      "CamperSiteLatitude" : -42.508695,
      "CamperSiteLongitude" : 147.916617,
      "CamperSiteName" : "Encampment Cove Walk"
    }
```

and this is my code

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Campsite");

Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo(country);
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        list.clear();
        Map<String, List<String>> mapImage = (Map<String, List<String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        Double lat = (Double)map.get("CamperSiteLatitude");
        Double lng = (Double)map.get("CamperSiteLongitude");
        LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        String CampSiteName = String.valueOf(map.get("CamperSiteName"));
        String CampSitePostID = (String) map.get("CamperSiteID");
        //String CampSiteImage = mapImage.get("CamperSiteImages");
        list.add(String.valueOf(newLocation));
        //listImage.add(CampSiteImage);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try{
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(listImage.get(i).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes,0,imageAsBytes.length);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(listTitle.get(i)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(CampSiteName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),CampSitePostID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay, I changed my context.

Comment: So you need to get the data inside `CamperSiteImages`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have two questions, first, i need to get CamperSiteImages value because I want to replace marker. Second I need to get CamperSiteID when I click the onMarkerClick then I will change to other fragment, but now when I clicked the marker I always got same CamperSiteID

Comment: I cannot see any "country" field inside the  "-MfS3VgBGROs_afkVrjl" node.

Comment: @AlexMamo I remove it... and updated context.

Answer (score 1):

This seems wrong:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapImage = (Map<String, List<String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

The list of images is stored in the `CamperSiteImages` property of the snapshot, so to get it you need:

```
List<String> mapImage = (List<String>) dataSnapshot.child("CamperSiteImages").getValue();
```

Comment: thx, has other question, how can get CamperSiteID when I use the `setOnMarkerClickListener`

Comment: And could I compress bitmap? This is my method. `bitmap = Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(CampSiteImage).withBitmap().fitCenter().resize(100,100).asBitmap().get();`